# Error 404: cordova-plugin-file when trying to install cordova-plugin-zip for iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, registry, http-status-code-404

When trying to install the cordoba-plugin-zip using:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/zip.git
```

as documented (https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-zip),

I get the below 404 error message. Has the cordova-plugin-file its trying to reference been moved? How can I tell the plugin to look for it elsewhere if so?

```
Installing "cordova-plugin-zip" for ios
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-file" via plugin registry
npm http GET http://registry.cordova.io/cordova-plugin-file
npm http 404 http://registry.cordova.io/cordova-plugin-file
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-zip':Error: 404 Not Found: cordova-plugin-file
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This plugin now depends on **cordova-plugin-file** (which is not available on cordova.io for now because it is an unreleased version of **org.apache.cordova.file**, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8806).
So this dependency needs to be installed from its GitHub repository, like this:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file.git
```

And then you can install **cordova-plugin-zip**:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/zip.git
```

Note: if you use any other plugin dependending on org.apache.cordova.file (like org.apache.cordova.file-transfer or org.apache.cordova.media), you will have to replace them with their GitHub repositiories too.

Comment: Cordova has moved its plugins to NPM now, so does this explanation need to be updated? `cordova plugin add SOME_PLUGIN` gives me 404 and I found out you now have to do `npm install SOME_PLUGIN`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct thing to do is to only download released versions of the plugin by fetching from the (now obsolete) http://plugins.cordova.io registy, or from npm:

Old registry:

```
cordova plugin add org.chromium.zip
```

New registry:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-zip
```

Note that you need `cordova` v5.0.0 to be able to fetch from the new registry (NPM)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-zip.git
```

Or this:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-zip
```

Comment: unfortunately I still get the same 404 error for cordoba-plugin-zip